# Primality testing: How to make sure not to test numbers which are multiples of already tested numbers?

Tags: python-3.x, math

Here is my code:

```
from math import sqrt


def isPrime(value):
    a = []
    for i in range(1, int(sqrt(value)) + 1):
        if value <= 3:
            return value
        if value % 2 == 0:
            break
        if value % i == 0:
            a.append(i)
            i += 1
            continue
        elif value % i != 0:
            a = a
            continue
    if len(a) == 1:
        return value
    else:
        pass
```

I want to be able to use this for testing big numbers too, but as fast as possible.

Comment: If you really want to test big numbers, throw away this idea of testing for primality by trial division and learn about the Miller-Rabin test instead. In any event, this has been a massively-studied problem. Have you attempted to explore the literature?

Comment: @JohnColeman I don't understand the implementation on Miller-Rabin test, could you help out with that?

Comment: It is a somewhat involved topic. If the Wikipedia article is not enough, I recommend the book "Public Key Cryptography" by  Lynn Margaret Batten as a good introduction if you want to understand some of the theory. It has a chapter on primality testing (as well as Maple code which is easy enough to translate to Python). Since Python's `pow` function already implements an efficient modular exponentiation, it is possible to write an efficient Miller-Rabin test in just a couple dozen lines of Python Code.

Answer (score 1):

## Primality testing with the Rabin-Miller algorithm

## Used [Wikipedia: Primality testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#cite_note-12)

```
import math


def initial_data(number):
    count = 0
    goree = number - 1
    floor = number // 2
    while goree % 2 == 0:
        goree //= 2
        count += 1
    results = [floor, count]
    return results


def test_values(num):
    test_vals = []
    if num < 2047:
        test_vals = [2]
    elif num < 1373653:
        test_vals = [2, 3]
    elif num < 9080191:
        test_vals = [31, 73]
    elif num < 25326001:
        test_vals = [2, 3, 5]
    elif num < 3215031751:
        test_vals = [2, 3, 5, 7]
    elif num < 4759123141:
        test_vals = [2, 7, 61]
    elif num < 1122004669633:
        test_vals = [2, 13, 23, 1662803]
    elif num < 2152302898747:
        test_vals = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
    elif num < 3474749660383:
        test_vals = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
    elif num < 341550071728321:
        test_vals = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]
    elif num < 3825123056546413051:
        test_vals = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23]
    elif num < 2**64:
        test_vals = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37]
    elif num < 318665857834031151167461:
        test_vals = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37]
    elif num < 3317044064679887385961981:
        test_vals = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41]
    return test_vals


def rabin_miller(num):
    base_primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97,
                   101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197,
                   199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239,241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313,
                   317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449,
                   457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521,523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587,
                   593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661,673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709,
                   719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853,
                   857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991,
                   997]
    if num <= 1:
        return False
    elif num in base_primes:
        return True
    else:

        for value in base_primes:  # making sure value does not have prime factors in
            if num not in base_primes and num % value == 0:
                return False
        data = initial_data(num)
        s = data[1]
        d = data[0]
        res = False
        testing_values = []
        if num < 3317044064679887385961981:
            testing_values = test_values(num)  # Get values of a to be used from test_values
        else:
            testing_values = [2, min(num - 1, int(2 * (math.log1p(num - 1))**2))]
        for a in testing_values:
            for r in range(1, s + 1):
                power = (2**r)*d

                if pow(a, d, num) != 1 and pow(a, power, num) != 1:
                    res = False

                elif pow(a, d, num) == 1 or pow(a, power, num) == 1:
                    return True
                else:
                    continue
        if res:
            return False
        else:
            return False

print(rabin_miller(5547337572376305111955330958342147474062293202868155909393))
```

This will work very fast for values greater than 64-bits, any hint and comment aimed at improving this code both in accuracy and efficiency (time efficiency) are welcomed.

> The base_primes list was obtained using and improved version of the
>   code in this question: [Primality testing: How to make sure not to
>   test numbers which are multiples of already tested numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559224/primality-testing-how-to-make-sure-not-to-test-numbers-which-are-multiples-of-a?noredirect=1#comment74171182_43559224)

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks for your advices, this is what I could do with the resources I found. Let me know if any improvements can be done.

Comment: Doesn't really seem to be Miller-Rabin

Comment: @JohnColeman It sure is more deterministic but the base is Miller-Rabin

Comment: I see -- you are using a deterministic variant whose correctness depends on the Riemann Hypothesis being true. Why avoid the probabilistic version since the probability of getting a false positive can be made lower than the probability of a random hardware failure when running the deterministic version (no computer program when run on actual hardware can give absolute certainty).

Comment: In any event, I had read about this deterministic variant before but hadn't seen it implemented in Python, so +1. The theoretical drawback of relying on unproven assumptions is unlikely to have any practical implications. Even though it is impossible to quantify, it is vanishingly unlikely that the Riemann Hypothesis will be disproven by having this algorithm certify a composite number as prime.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of the randomized test:

```
import random

#The following function finds s and d in
#n-1 = 2^s*d with d odd

def findSD(n):
    s = 0
    d = n-1
    while d % 2 == 0:
        s = s + 1
        d = d//2
    return s,d

def checkBase(a,n):
    s,d = findSD(n)
    x = pow(a,d,n)
    if x == 1 or x == n-1:
        return "probable prime"
    else:
        for i in range(s-1):
            x = pow(x,2,n)
            if x == 1:
                return "composite"
            elif x == n-1:
                return "probable prime"
        #if you get to this stage, -1 not reached despite s-1
        #squarings -- so must be composite
        return "composite"

def MSR(n,k):
    #tests is an odd number is prime
    for i in range(k):
        a = random.randint(2,n-2)
        if checkBase(a,n) == "composite":
            return "composite"
    #if you get here n has survived k potential witnesses, so
    return "probable prime"

def prime(n):
    smallPrimes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19]

    for p in smallPrimes:
        if n == p:
            return True
        elif n % p == 0:
            return False

    if MSR(n,20) == "composite":
        return False
    else:
        return True

def prime(n):
    smallPrimes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19]

    for p in smallPrimes:
        if n == p:
            return True
        elif n % p == 0:
            return False

    if MSR(n,20) == "composite":
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

You can use it to fish for primes:

```
def findPrime(maxN):
    while True:
        n = random.randint(3,maxN)
        if prime(n):
            return n
```

Typical run:

```
>>> findPrime(2**512)
3416363469318261052788311737860856549293100664891633139661459849835325883152102949928216754211470387640525391249585700324869443369023574938398397274187333
```

Comment: I saw a code similar to this once, but what can you tell me about its running time? The one I wrote takes an eternity to evaluate the sum of first one million primes (more than 30 minutes actually)

Comment: For the sum of the first 1 million primes use the sieve of Eratosthenes to generate the list rather than testing each candidate.  It is known that the nth prime is < `n*(log(n)+log(log(n))` (see the Wikipedia page on the prime number theorem) which works out to about 16.45 million -- so sieve that range. If you are finding all primes -- no need to test them one by one.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, the sieve of Eratosthenes is easy to implement and runs very fast for this particular purpose of summing consecutive primes. I've got a run time of 6 seconds for the 1st one million primes.